# Assault ships v. Interceptors

Tags: eve-online

What are the benefits of an assault ship over an interceptor?

I played some significant time ago, and was working towards an assault ship for my solo agent missions and general 0.6 ratting (NPC pirate hunting), but I've no idea if this is a good idea any more (or even then).

So:

a) What are the main uses of each
b) Which would most benefit the style of play mentioned above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assault ships** are a bit heavier and ment for "prolonged" fights. Have better tanking capability. Can deal a nice amount of damage as well as take in a nice amount of damage.

**Interceptors** are very light, very fast version of the tech 1 counterpart. Have very low tanking capability but rely heavily on speed as a "tank". Can deal a very nice amount of damage.

In proper hands these ships can be very dangerous. I think they were created to enhance wolf pack tactics.

You need to be aware that in some cases a more skilled pilot in a cruiser will be in your way. You have a great chance of dying.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is, the interceptor is for speed tanking and holding the enemy in place until someone comes and kills him. The Assaultship is for doing good DPS.

An assaultship can normally orbit a BS too close for the tracking of the BS to hit him. All the while doing a lot of Damage (for a frigate).

Comment: using a cheap rifter with afterburner 1, i can easly do this circling on a cruiser. would it be that much easier/better in an interceptor? i do like the fact that interceptors have over double the warp speed (12-14au/s) but that seems more of a travel feature then to help with battling others.

Comment: Having been in a BC surrounded by frigates in a mission today, I can well understand the benefits; unless they're carrying a smartbomb (like I always do). BOOM *pop* *pop* *pop*

Comment: The interceptor will have a much larger orbit in most cases. How close it is depends on your Navigation skills. Try the following: find the closest stable orbit in a Rifter around a friend, check your angular velocity. Do the same with an interceptor. The one with higher angular velocity is harder to hit - just make sure that it is not higher than your tracking.

Comment: The double warp speed also helps with running away from system-blockades